# Is this rust on my lally column safe to sand and seal?

Tags: basement, foundation, column

first time poster here. I’m in the process of finishing my basement and have reached rough framing near my only steel lally column. I’ve noticed rust in the past but just took a good look and am wondering if it is safe to sand and seal, or if it is beyond repair.

There are no gaping holes anywhere. Slight surface rust throughout and a spot or two where the steel has a few divots from the rust. Slightly bulging here or there but nothing too extreme.

My plan would be to sand, seal with a rusty metal primer, and re paint.

Thoughts? Thanks!

[image][image][image][image]

Answer (score 1):

That rust looks very mild, even near the floor where I'd expect it to be the worst. I'd have no concerns about wiping it down and spraying it with a primer designed to handle rust. You probably wouldn't need to do much sanding unless you plan to leave it exposed and want it smooth. Even then I'd consider a textured paint.

Comment: Thanks so much for the feedback. That first image where there is a divot in the steel so what worries me. You cannot see to the concrete within but the steel is definitely eaten away a bit (about a half dollar sized). Does that change anything?

Comment: I can't see a divot from the angle of the photo, but are you sure it's from rust and not just sloppy manufacturing?

Comment: very good point…. That I cannot attest to but I can clarify by saying instead of being a uniform smith finish around, in the pic I added the area circled in red just feels rough in indented a bit. I may be overreacting here but I’m not familiar with support columns!

Comment: Take a wire brush to it. If the rust comes off with little effort, you're fine. If it crumbles away into a deeper flaw, seek local expertise.

Comment: I used some fine grit sandpaper with an orbital sander (lightly) and the rust seems to come off with the exception of the nooks and crannies I can’t reach. Assuming a wire brush will do the trick! Thanks so much! 

Not to keep asking questions but any recommendation on the appropriate primer/sealant to use in my case?

Comment: Strictly cosmetic; do what you want to change the appearance.  The localized spot likely developed while in storage at the pipe yard Typically the pipes lay on wood sleepers . the bottom pipe may have been on the damp wood for years.

Comment: Use any primer that specifies bare metal.

Comment: Right. Product recommendations are off topic here. Stick with well-known brands and read the label.